# Vector parallel to a plane 3x+2z=3

Tags: geometry, vectors, analytic-geometry

I have a plane whose equation is $3x+2z=3$

My question is, is  vector: $(0,1,0)$ parallel to the plane? Or how do I determine if a vector is parallel to a certain plane?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A normal to your plane comes from the coefficients of $x,y,z$  i.e. $(3,0,2)$.

If $(0,1,0)$ is parallel to the plane, then it is perpendicular to the normal, which you can check with the dot product.

Answer (score 0):

Compute the CrossProduct $$[3,0,2]\times [0,1,0]$$

Comment: so in case they are parallel the result will be zero right?

Comment: Then the cross product gives $\vec{0}$

Comment: Your answer is right!

Comment: can i also assume something by computing the dot product?

Comment: No, the dot product gives no parallelism